Mock TCP-RX/TX in python code for testing in CI/CD pipeline
My python-based project contains three different modules, a RX-module, a processing module and a TX-module. Both RX and TX communicate via TCP/IP with their external counterparts. However, there are multiple possible counterparts for both ends with different protocols each, thus I have to test all possible combinations.
For integration testing locally I therefore create three threads (external RX-counterpart, external TX-counterpart and thread containing module combination to test). Within the counterpart threads, I create an additional TCP/IP-server/client, to connect to the main modules in test at 127.0.0.1 and to feed/received test data.
This approach works fine when running pytest locally, but not within a gitlab-pipeline, as it appears that TCP/IP-connections there are blocked. Thus all tests related to the RX-/TX-modules fail in the pipeline, while they pass in the local test.
What kind of options do I have here? I have found multiple questions asking about mocking the TCP-part, however the (in general) accepted answers all focus on "start a second thread for a testing server", something which is not available in my case.

Ideally, write your code in a way that just accepts text or bytes without needing to know about the actual transport layer. See sans I/O for a basic discussion of this idea. That makes testing quite a lot easier and avoids the need for monkey-patching or emulating IO devices/clients/etc. Some reproducible code, and examples of what you've tried, what is not working, etc. might help you get a more specific answer. Alternatively, address your environment constraints -- why can't you take the approaches that have been suggested like a testing server?
